# Screen Flickering and non-functional After suspend [Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, Lenovo Thinkpad 14s gen3]

Tags: suspend, lenovo, hdmi, freeze, flicker

I was attempting to fix an issue where the HDMI port on my lenovo does not work with Ubuntu 22.04. Two suggestions I tried were attempting to select a different Nvidia driver in software updates, and re-configuring the display manager or trying lightdm. I will disclaim that I am very inexperienced with linux and am by no means proficient in any type of computer science or work with operating systems. I am using linux at the behest of a research advisor.

After trying those two solutions (which did not fix the HDMI problem), a new problem appeared where now after the computer suspends, either via command or by closing the lid, when I open it up a very quick code message flashes (it is too fast to photograph and there is no way to screenshot). The screen afterwards alternates between black and showing whatever was on the screen when the lid was closed. When black the computer is unresponsive. When showing the screen the mouse is responsive but nothing else is. There is no way to interface with the computer at this point, and I have to emergency shut down by holding down the power button. After starting up again, the computer works completely fine as long as it doesn't suspend. A clue I have is  on boot-up after emergency shut down, the login screen looks messed up. It looks like a distorted home screen with the login options off to the side instead of center. I don't really know (since I am not linux proficient) what information might be useful to provide, and can of course provide anything else if instructed how.
Thanks so much in advance!
Jared